# Yii2-mongodb: how to add database fetched items in dropdown list

Tags: mongodb, yii2

I am trying to add the team names(to be fetched from mongoDB) in the form to let user select the form name.

I am not getting how to add the database fetched form names in the dropdown list.
It should search based on organization_id first & then form_name.

what i am doing is this:

```
  <?= $form->field($model1, 'form_name')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(CreateTeam::find(array('organization_id' => Yii::$app->session['organization_id']))->all(), 'form_name'));  ?>
```

It is showing me an error that missing the third argument. What could be the third argument in that case???

Answer (score 2):

I went through issue with fetching record from country collection to serve record in state form

I got solution as below (considering as my state form)

```
use app\models\Countries;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

$countries=Countries::find()->all();
$listData=ArrayHelper::map(Countries::find()->all(),function ($model){return  (string)$model->_id;},'name');
echo $form->field($model, 'countries_id')->dropDownList($listData, ['prompt'=>'Select...']);
```

Hope I was able to let you understand !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in `ArrayHelper::map()` first three parameters are required, so you are definitely calling this method wrong.

Check out official documentation for [map()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#map%28%29-detail).

The second parameter represents the actual values in database (usually they are primary keys), the third - readable text.

Assuming your primary key is `id` it should be:

```
$models = CreateTeam::find([
    'organization_id' => Yii::$app->session['organization_id'],
])->all();

$items = ArrayHelper::map($models, 'id', 'form_name');

<?= $form->field($model1, 'form_name')->dropDownList($items) ?>
```

Comment: hey it is throwing the error: illegal offset type for $models in the arrayHelper::map line...

Comment: well the way to do it in controller is the right method to work with. I found solution differently

Answer (score 0):

```
    $collection2 = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('teamdashboard');
    $models = $collection2->find(array('organization_id' => Yii::$app-   >session['organization_id']));

    $items = ArrayHelper::getColumn($models, 'team_name');

    return $this->render('teamdashboard', ['model1' => $model1, 'model2' =>  $model2, 'items' => $items]);
```

This one works fine for mongodb...